# url rewrite working but on the wrong page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url rewrite working, but I am unsure how I get it so that it is only applicable to the index page of my search folder.

I am using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /search/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With the following folder structure:

```
/
    /public_html
        /search
            -index.php (inside search dir)
```

When I use my above url rewrite I have the following output:

```
http://blah.com/home/
```

The only issue is that instead of redirecting to my home folder it goes to the search page and runs a search for home.

My desired output would be:

```
http://blah.com/search/query
```

where query is what I am actually searching for.

My current php code inside my search directory index.php:

```
include('../secure.php');
$search = $_GET['q'];
```

**How do I get it so that the rewrite only happens on the index.php page of my search folder?**

Answer (score 0):

Save your `.htaccess` inside `public_html` dir with following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried both ways and neither way has worked. Cheers for trying though!

Comment: Try the **updated** which is well tested code, working in my local.

Comment: Nothing, I still have http://blah.com/search/index.php?q=multiple :( could it have something to do with how my url is passed from the initial page?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what do you mean by I stil have `...`. If you accessed `blah.com/search/hello` , it will be identical to accessing `blah.com/search/index.php?q=hello`. But you will not be redirect to anywhere. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that is what I would like, I want to go to my search dir and then "get" the hello parameter and use that as my search criteria. I hope that clears it up a bit better?

Comment: You should get the `search criteria` in `search/index.php` : `$qry = $_GET['q']`. Can you please post the value of `$qry` when you browse `/search/hello`. I am surprise hearing it is not working.. anyway.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include my php as per your request